# Get percentual of remaining slices of Pie Chart - NVD3

Tags: svg, d3.js, pie-chart, nvd3.js

In some cases of my Pie Chart, I would like to show the user **the percentage relative to slices of the Pie Chart instead of showing the values of the slices**.

For example: I have three slices in my pie: `A` representing 70% of the pie, `B` representing 15% of the pie and `C` representing 15% of the pie.

When I click to hide the slice `A` I want to show to the user the percentage of the remaining slices, in this example it'll be `B` = 50% and `C` = 50%.

**Is it possible in NVD3?**

**Important:** I don't want to reload the chart when click to hide some slice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `chart.tooltipContent` to override the chart tooltip label. The following is adapted from the live code example on NVD3's website. http://nvd3.org/livecode/#codemirrorNav

Example: http://plnkr.co/edit/UiGLIj?p=preview

```
nv.addGraph(function() {
  var chart = nv.models.pieChart()
      .x(function(d) { return d.label })
      .y(function(d) { return d.value })
      .showLabels(true);

  chart.tooltipContent(function(key, x, obj){
    var enabledTotal = data[0].values
        .filter(function(item){return !item.disabled;})
        .reduce(function(a, b){return a + b.value}, 0);

    return Math.round((obj.value/enabledTotal) * 100) + "%";
  })

    d3.select("#chart svg")
        .datum(data)
      .transition().duration(1200)
        .call(chart);

  return chart;
});
```

Comment: In my code, this structure of jSon object doesn't work. Could you tell me why? Here's a jsFiddle of it: http://jsfiddle.net/Zanelli/E7j7B/1/ And with my current jSon structure, I can't recover the percentual, like you said.

Comment: PS: The structure used is the same as the example I downloaded the site NVD3.

Comment: I think in the most recent development branches they are updating the format models/pie.js takes from an object to a array. If you make a fiddle I'll be happy to take a look at it.

Comment: If you introspect `.reduce(function ... )` your summing function should return `a + b.y;` rather than `a + b.value;`

Comment: With this worked fine! How I can't see this before? Anyway, thank you again for help!